# SQL Developer unexpected double quote when I copy value from query result

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm doing a simple select query on a table :

SELECT NEP_ID FROM Table1;

Result :
[image: Query result]

But when I select for example the first value of the query result (here '0019025') and paste it on the worksheet or a text editor I get : '"0019025"'. I don't understand why I get these double quotes, seems there is something wrong with the values in NEP_ID column. (I don't have this problem on similar tables).

I've tried to do a to_char update, but it doesn't help.

```
desc Table1
Name         Null Type          
------------ ---- ------------- 
SEGMENT_CODE      CHAR(3)       
NEP_ID            VARCHAR2(255)
```

Comment: @Stidgeon No I have another table with the same columns en datatypes and I haven't this problem..